# Spinner starting activity

Tags: android, spinner

I am having issue with starting activity from spinner. When I change value of spinner activity starts, but when I press back button I can't go back to select another spinner value. It stores my choice and starts activity again and again, something like loop.

```
spiner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiner1);

        spiner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListenerWrapper(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                String str=spiner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
//              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(str.equals("Pravougaonik")) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(Pocetna.this, Pravougaonik.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if(str.equals("Trougao")) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(Pocetna.this, Trougao.class);
                    startActivity(i);
}
}
@Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
```

And Class:

```
public class OnItemSelectedListenerWrapper implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private int lastPosition;
    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    public OnItemSelectedListenerWrapper(OnItemSelectedListener aListener) {
        lastPosition = 0;
        listener = aListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aParentView, View aView, int aPosition, long anId) {
        if (lastPosition == aPosition) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Ignoring onItemSelected for same position: " + aPosition);
        } else {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Passing on onItemSelected for different position: " + aPosition);
            listener.onItemSelected(aParentView, aView, aPosition, anId);
        }
        lastPosition = aPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> aParentView) {
        listener.onNothingSelected(aParentView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unselect the spinner value on the `onPause` or `onResume` methods of the starting activity.

Comment: I am having issue doint that, can you be more specific, please. I tried with this public void onRestart() {
  spiner1.setSelection(0);
  super.onResume();
  
 }

Comment: Try: `@Override public void onResume() { super.onResume(); spinner1.setSelection(0);}` for now. If this does not work (which I doubt), try replacing `onResume` with `onPause`.

Comment: @AleksandarPanic You shouldn't call `super.onResume()` from the method `onRestart()` - normally you want to call the SAME method name.

Comment: This is good. I swaped spinner1.setSelection and onResume()